# Spring Security OAuth2 revoke token does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have following configuration in my Spring Boot app:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myOauth2ClientDetailsService")
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // set custom exception translator
        endpoints.exceptionTranslator(e -> {
            if (e instanceof OAuth2Exception) {
                OAuth2Exception exception = (OAuth2Exception) e;
                return ResponseEntity
                        .status(exception.getHttpErrorCode())
                        .body(new MyWLoginException(exception.getMessage()));
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        });
        // other settings
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new MyTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(-10)
public static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuditorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
             .and().csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        defaultAccessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(defaultAccessTokenConverter);
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter() {
        return new MyUserAuthenticationConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

}

Also, I have special endpoint to revoke tokens, which handles request in following method:

```
@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;
@Autowired
private AuthorizationServerTokenServices authorizationServerTokenServices;
@Autowired
private ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices;
...
final String tokenValue = ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getTokenValue();
        final OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(token);
        boolean authRemoved = ((DefaultTokenServices) authorizationServerTokenServices).revokeToken(tokenValue); // <- true
        boolean resourceRemoved = ((DefaultTokenServices) resourceServerTokenServices).revokeToken(tokenValue); // <- true
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

There are no any errors. I see that token services return `true` (removed). But when I call any endpoint with old access token it works like this token still alive. But I remove token from both auth server and resource server. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Token revocation won't work using JWT because the expiration of the token it's embedded in it. Your authorization server won't catch any information about the token after issued. So maybe you should try using a [JdbcTokenStore](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.html) in your authorization server to hold your tokens in a DB and then revoke them as desired (or could be in memory too). If your apps are separated you can use a [RemoteTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.html) to validate your tokens.

[Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-revoke-tokens) is a tutorial that show you how to get this done.

Comment: I guess you are right. I plan to use RedisTokenStore. I think I need single and clear storage for tokens